# Will a Windows 10 in-place upgrade reset all drivers?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-10-upgrade, amd-ryzen

I'm having problems with random restarts of my system while it's idling or under low load (Windows lockscreen, on desktop, browsing websites). I never had any crashes while playing games. I can't figure out why that is happening, because if it's a power supply problem I'd expect it to happen while under high load. I pretty much tried everything (BIOS update, chipset update, GPU driver update), but it is still happening. Now I'm wondering if it could be caused by Windows 10 itself or maybe broken drivers.

Would an in-place upgrade purge all the installed drivers, but keep the data and programs?

Comment: Only if you choose to keep nothing

Comment: @Ramhound are you sure? I'm fairly positive drivers are updated to the latest version if they are available in windows update.

Comment: Is there another way to reset Windows to "clean" state, but keep programs/data? It would be great if you could have a Windows 10 installation that is just as freshly installed (no additional drivers, only the ones provides by MS), but with all the personal data and programs/apps.

Comment: You can reset to a "clean" state by keeping just data (I have done this myself once). But most times a normal repair (keep data and apps) works well. If apps are misbehaved, let them go, keep only data and reinstall apps after.

Comment: @LPChip - Yes; Windows Update will keep most generic device drivers that are published to Windows Update updated. Which means more than likely those drivers are already updated.  The only way a driver will be replaced is if the driver needs to be updated but that won’t happen if the in-place upgrade is the same version (same driver will be used).  Honestly the description doesn’t sound like corrupt drivers

Comment: @John User basroil in [Computer freezes at random when doing low to idle CPU usage tasks](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/computer-freezes-at-random-when-doing-low-to-idle-cpu-usage-tasks.2596868/) on Tom's Hardware has this suggestion: "Try changing your power settings from the default 5% min 100%max to 75%min 100%max. If that clears things up, it's almost 100% a PSU issue." Where to change the power setting: [How to Use Maximum CPU Power in Windows 10](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-10/how-to-use-maximum-cpu-power-in-windows-10/).

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm using the "Ryzen Balanced" power plan and that sets it to 99% min and 100% max.

Comment: @John A search on Google for "windows 10 ryzen idle crashes" brings up quite a few possible reasons.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the tip. I didn't actually know so many people had that problem.

Answer (score 3):

When you run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link, drivers in the Microsoft Windows Catalogue are updated / reinstalled. Some drivers (notably like BIOS in a non-Surface Pro machine) are not in the catalogue and are not updated.

When you complete the Repair Install, look in Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, Reliability History and you can see the drivers that were updated.

Comment: Is a "repair install" the same as an "in-place upgrade"?

Comment: They are very close. Both will rewrite the operating system and create a windows.old file that you can restore from. Regular updates are different.

Comment: in-place upgrade will install a newer version of the OS though.

Comment: @LPChip Not necessarily. I did my in-place upgrade yesterday. I had Windows 10 1909 and installed 1909 again. It kept my files, programs and drivers. I will see if it fixed my stability issues.

Comment: I see, interesting.

Comment: I installed some faulty drivers and now keep getting blue screens. Will an inplace upgrade go back to the drivers that were installed originally by Windows Update, even if these drivers are older than the ones I installed?

Answer (score 0):

SW - Have you considered any malware or infection or rootkit? download malwarebytes and enable "scan for rootkits" option in settings before updating it's database and scanning whole pc

HW - Check the heat in your GPU, motherboard and definitely CPU with an application like "Speccy" and compare with the same hardware on internet. Your heatsinks might get loosen or thermalpaste is worn maybe. Try to remember if you computer had any kind of shock like falling or bending before this started to happen. afaik, mainboards shutdown computer in case of too high temperature to protect hardware.

SW - In case you have things got wrong with you drivers, try to install another OS that wil not use windows hardware drivers like Ubuntu. it's just about 2gbs and easy to install and remove if you read the prescription well. install it and browse in internet for a while. if there's no problem, you can make sure you have nothing wrong with your hardware. besides: you can install an antivirus for linux and scan your windows drives while all is frozen including possible viruses.

don't spend a week for any of the above, remember, time is valuable. :)

Comment: I feel like things are either pointing to a Windows problem or HW (PSU or mainboard). No viruses or malware, all temps are fine. The problem with the crashes is, that they happen very irregularly. I didn't have problems for months, then I had a random restart, then like a week later again, then after a month, then 3 days ago and today I even had 2 restarts in 3 hours...